# Can two Pagerduty services use the same email address?

Tags: pagerduty

I am setting up technical services in Pagerduty for a team and want all of them to use the same email integration, specifically, the same email address.

I see that I am allowed to associate the same email address to multiple technical services.

Is this the right thing to do? If not, what are the drawbacks?

Answer (score 2):

A drawback to this is that you'll get an incident for all of those services that share the email.  Depending on the size of your setup, this will cause a lot of noise for oncall.

If you want a single email, I'd suggest a global event rule or event orchestration.  This products a single routing key and email but still allows you to use rules to route the incoming event to a specific service.

https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/rulesets#global-rulesets

https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/event-orchestration